# C# Draw image implemention

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics

Im trying to make kind of `Grahpics.DrawImage` implemention using **unsafe code and pointers** of course.

In this case im trying to draw a small bitmap on a bigger width(both 32bppArgb).

This is my code

```
   private static unsafe void Draw(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap bmp2, int xPoint, int yPoint)
    {

        BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);

        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
        IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;

        int stride = bmData.Stride;
        int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;

        int nWidth = bmp2.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp2.Height;

        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
        p += yPoint * stride + xPoint * 4;
        byte* p2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();
        p2 += sourceY * stride2 + sourceX * 4;
        int bytes = nWidth * 4;

        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x <nWidth; x++)
            {


                p[0] = p2[0];
                p[1] = p2[1];
                p[2] = p2[2];
                p[3] = p2[3];

            }

            p += 4;
            p2 += 4;
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
        bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
    }
```

this is the updated code

Comment: You are copying the image to itself. For `b2` you should use `scan02` instead of `scan0`. You should also use `stride2` for `b2`. Then you should use the `stride` and `stride2` to move `b` and `b2` to the next line instead of assuming that the next line starts immediately after the current. There can be padding between the lines, and the stride can even be negative when the image is stored upside down in memory.

Comment: @Guffa ohh.. didnt see it... thanks man!

Comment: @Guffa wait.. now i'm getting an exception here `   p[0] = p2[0]; ** attempted to read or write protected memory**

Comment: I just added more in the comment above.

Comment: @Guffa first of all its `p` haha. about moving the `p` you ment instead of `p+=4` to use only`  `p += (yPoint * stride) + (xPoint * 4); `?

Comment: Hehe, I read the `p` upside down for some reason. :) The `+=4` is to move to the next pixel. In the outer loop you would need `p += stride - nWidth * 4;` and the corresponding for `p2`.

Comment: i still see nothing.. updated the code so you could see the changes @Guffa

Comment: I doubt this will be any faster than using DrawImage.

Comment: @TaW it is.. there is a massive diffrence.. just measured the time :) could you help man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes to make it work:

- Use `ImageLockMode.WriteOnly` in the `LockBits` call for the image that you want to write to.
- Don't move `p2` according to `xPoint` and `yPoint`.

I saw that you set the pointers inside the outer loop, so then you would not need to move the pointers at the end of the loop. I recommend that you calculcate the starting points outside the outer loop, and move the pointers inside it.

I also recommend these changes that I did:

- Add checks for the bounds of the images, so that you don't accidentally try to draw outside the image.
- Make the method `void`. Returning a bitmap suggests that it creates a new bitmap rather than changing one of the bitmap that you pass into it.

I added a `pixelBytes` parameter to make it usable for different pixel formats. (Mostly because I happened to have JPEGs, not PNGs to test with.)

Code:

```
private static unsafe void Draw(Bitmap bmp, Bitmap bmp2, int xPoint, int yPoint, int pixelBytes) {

  BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
  BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);

  IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
  IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;

  int stride = bmData.Stride;
  int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;

  int nWidth = bmp2.Width;
  int nHeight = bmp2.Height;

  int sourceX = 0;
  int sourceY = 0;

  if (xPoint < 0) {
    sourceX = -xPoint;
    nWidth -= sourceX;
    xPoint = 0;
  }
  if (yPoint < 0) {
    sourceY = -yPoint;
    nHeight -= sourceY;
    yPoint = 0;
  }
  if (xPoint + nWidth > bmp.Width) {
    nWidth = bmp.Width - xPoint;
  }
  if (yPoint + nHeight > bmp.Height) {
    nHeight = bmp.Height - yPoint;
  }

  if (nWidth > 0 && nHeight > 0) {

    byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
    p += yPoint * stride + xPoint * pixelBytes;
    byte* p2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();
    p2 += sourceY * stride2 + sourceX * pixelBytes;

    int bytes = nWidth * pixelBytes;

    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < bytes; x++) {
        p[0] = p2[0];
        p++;
        p2++;
      }
      p += stride - nWidth * pixelBytes;
      p2 += stride2 - nWidth * pixelBytes;
    }

  }

  bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
  bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
}
```

Comment: thanks man you're awesome! Your code is straight to the point! +1

Comment: one last thing just mesaured the excceution time of this method, and it was way slower than mine(i know it didnt worked but still). i think the main bottleneck is that the  inner loop is running `bytes` time..couldnt it run faster? can you just  update somthing in my code so it would work? A huge huge huge thanks bro! you'r answer is awesome but it's a little slow.. thanks in advance!

Comment: @Slashy: If you remove the `pixelBytes` parameter and make it loop pixels instead of bytes, you should get that performance back.

Comment: removed the paramater.. now i should write `4` instead right? what do you mean make it loop pixels? @Guffa

Comment: @Slashy: Yes. Use `x < nWidth` in the loop, all the `p[0]` to `p[3]` copies, and `+= 4` to increase the pointers.

Comment: Again ... Then i dont see nothing changed now.. updated the code acorrding to your instructions- correct me if somthing wrong(yea i guess i didn't understand you 100% :))

Comment: @Slashy: You should keep the original code in the question and add the updated below, otherwise others won't understand the question and why there is an answer. The `+= 4` should be inside the inner loop, and the adjustment to the next line still inside the outer loop.